# Gson howto parse different data types in a single array?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have an API response that includes METAR weather data as well as string error responses, both contained in the same "data" array. I am using Gson to parse the json response on Android. This works great until I get a string error response. I've tried my hand at trying to write a custom Gson deserializer with no luck. Can someone give me a working example or point me in the correct direction on how to handle this?

The response looks like this:

```
{
    "results": 4,
    "data": [
        {
            "icao": "KAJO",
            "name": "Corona Municipal",
            "observed": "05-11-2018 @ 18:56Z",
            "raw_text": "KAJO 051856Z AUTO VRB03KT 10SM CLR 23/08      A2989 RMK AO2 SLP129 T02330078 $",
            "barometer": {
                "hg": 29.890000000000001,
                "kpa": 101.22,
                "mb": 1012.9
            },
            "clouds": [
                {
                    "code": "CLR",
                    "text": "Clear skies",
                    "base_feet_agl": 0,
                    "base_meters_agl": 0
                }
            ],
            "dewpoint": {
                "celsius": 8,
                "fahrenheit": 46
            },
            "elevation": {
                "feet": 535,
                "meters": 163
            },
            "flight_category": "VFR",
            "humidity_percent": 38,
            "temperature": {
                "celsius": 23,
                "fahrenheit": 73
            },
            "visibility": {
                "miles": "10",
                "meters": "16,093"
            },
            "wind": {
                "degrees": 0,
                "speed_kts": 3,
                "speed_mph": 3,
                "speed_mps": 2
            }
        },
        "KGNG METAR Currently Unavailable",
        "CXCY Invalid Station ICAO"
    ]
}
```

As you can see the "data" array may return a metar object (I have this part working) or an unnamed error string. It is when I get the error string returned that my parsing fails.

As a test I wrote the following. But it is also not working. How can I parse the both the raw unnamed string and the metar object?

```
import com.google.gson.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Response.class, new MyDeserializer())
                .registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new String())
                .create();

        Response response = gson.fromJson(str_json, Response.class);
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

    static class MyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Response> {
        @Override
        public Response deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT
                ,JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            // Get the "data" element from the parsed json
            JsonElement data = json.getAsJsonObject().get("data    ");
            // Deserialize it. You use a new instance of Gson to avoid
            // infinite recursion
            return new Gson().fromJson(data, Response.class);

        }
    }
    /*===============================
     * Data Definitions
     *==============================*/
    class Response {
           public String  results;
           public List<Station> Stations;
    }

    class Station {
        public String name;
        public String icao;
    }

    public static String str_json = "{\n" +
            "    \"results\": 3,\n" +
            "    \"data\": [\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "           \"name\": \"Billings Logan Intl\"," +
            "           \"icao\":\"KBIL\"," +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"CYPG METAR Currently Unavailable\",\n" +
            "        \"KGNG METAR Currently Unavailable\"\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "}";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it would make thing seasier if you changed the DTOs a bit, for the `Response`

```
public class Response {
    public String results;
    public List<Station> data; // it is named data in JSON not Stations
}
```

Then the rest is done depending on how you would like to handle the error text. One easy way would be to just add error field to your `Station` so that it would be:

```
public class Station {
    public String name;
    public String icao;
    public String error;  // used if there is only error string
}
```

With a custom deserialiser like:

```
public class StationDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Station> {

    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public Station deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT
                ,JsonDeserializationContext context)
        throws JsonParseException {         
        try {
            return gson.fromJson(json, Station.class);
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            // it was not a Station object
            Station station = new Station();
            // so try to set the error string
            station.error = json.getAsString();
            return station;
        }
    }

}
```

The try to deserialize:

```
Response response = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Station.class, new StationDeserializer())
        .create()
        .fromJson(str_json, Response.class);
```

Checking if there is an `error` string in a `Station` or not you can see if the data is valid.

Comment: How can I get the getJsonTestResourceReader() method? I have Gson included using maven in my sample test project but cannot find this method.

Comment: @user693336 By coding it :) Sorry it was my copy/paste error. It was meant to be your JSON. That was just a method used to read a resource file.

Comment: Yes, I just replaced it with the str_json. Still getting errors when parsing though...

Comment: Thank you SOOOOO MUCH! I got it to work. You've no idea how I struggled with this!